# how to set different color of border of rectangle using stroke

Tags: android

How about, if just to get top border or left border using stroke. Is it possible to set different width for different borders

Comment: You need to add a few more details to your question.  What do you mean by "using stroke"?  You tag it Android, so this implies you are displaying something in Android?  openGl?

Answer (score 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#FAFAFA"/>
 <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#cccccc" />
 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"
/>

</shape>
```

Hope you can see the xml i am using. Thanks

Comment: does it use different color for different sides of rectangle too?